# Bluetooth Toggle on/off not showing windows 10

Tags: usb, audio, bluetooth

I know this question has been asked before As I have read
multiple different replys and answer's,
none of which are working for my device.

I have a HP Compaq;
running the latest version of windows 10 64bit,
The Motherboard is hp 3646h
intel chipset Q45/Q43
version: 786G7 v01.14

This device does not have bluetooth built into it,
I have brought two seperate USB Bluetooth drives,
& have uninstalled and re-installed the hardware, firmware or drivers multiple times.
I have had it working once, but it is a mission every single time.
The main windows toggle switch for bluetooth just does not show up in settings ever, Nor does it show up in the system's icon tray in the bottom right of the screen.

When viewing device manager, no bluetooth device shows up
or not atleast the Generic bluetooth item that normally should.

The only device that does show up is BTFASHE which is one of the usb
bluetooth dongle. But this still does not allow me to turn on bluetooth or search to find the speakers that I wish to use.

I have installed the intel bluetooth drivers, aswell as attempted repair, 
& before anyone suggest's it, yes I have also re-booted my computer and shut it down.
Why does the toggle button not even show up. This is annoying.
Has anyone had the same issues with windows 10?
Please help

Comment: Are you sure the dongles you're trying are compatible with Windows 10? If they are then their drivers should work and most of the times (the few I've tried) work without installing additional drivers. If you're sure then it's likely your Windows is the problem.

Comment: I Don't know for sure, but they should be, they are the latest version number of bluetooth, so I'm assuming that they would be compatible with the latest version of windows. I have now fixed this issue by installing a Wifi card that has bluetooth built into it. Bit annoying that I now have 2 usb bluetooth dongles that are useless. But atleast its working.